# Proper way of user authentication using an angular-seed scaffolded by yeoman generator angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication

#### Situation

I scaffolded the application using a yeoman generator angularjs, thus providing me a clean directory structure and framework structure. I'm just learning angularjs and using yeoman is a cleaner way to do things, and soc is pretty much achieved.

Now I am having a problem on where to put things, like services and factories, I am currently dealing with user authentication right now.

#### Basically

I have two routes as of the moment, one is `/` and one is `/secured`. I set this up so that I can really get started playing with authentication.

I found this article about [authenticating a user](https://vickev.com/#!/article/authentication-in-single-page-applications-node-js-passportjs-angularjs). And I found it really interesting, and I thought I could somehow understand it, and really I understood it, but I think I fail to understand some of the basics of how should factories and services should be used.

#### What I currently have

First, I do not have a backend service, because the app fails right on and writing a service won't be necessary right now, I can just write a simple php script that returns `401` status or `200`, but that wont be necessary right now, I want to work on the client side first.

In my `app.coffee` file

```
angular.module('myApp', [
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngSanitize',
'ngRoute'
])
.config ($routeProvider) ->
  $routeProvider
    .when '/',
      templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
      controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    .when '/secured',
      templateUrl: 'views/secured.html'
      controller: 'SecuredCtrl'
      resolve:
        loggedin: checkLoggedin // this is the wrong one
    .otherwise
      redirectTo: '/'
.config ($httpProvider) ->
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor')
```

In the article, it says create a function that checks if the user is loggedin or not, and in his [codebase](https://github.com/Anomen/AuthenticationAngularJS/blob/master/public/javascripts/app.js) he made that function inside the `config` method. And btw, he ain't using yeoman so that pretty much complicate things to me.

I thought that checking loggedin status is a factory or a service's job, so I thought of writing a factor for that like so

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory 'checkLoggedin', ($q, $timeout, $http, $location, $rootScope) ->
    deferred = $q.defer()

    $http.get('api/loggedin').success (user) ->
      if user isnt '0'
        $timeout(deferred.resolve, 0)
      else
        $rootScope.message = 'You need to be logged in.'
        $timeout(
          () -> deferred.reject(),
          0
        )
        $location.url '/login'
```

What is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the awesome angular-http-auth module - https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth

All you need to do is listen for the event 'auth-loginRequired' at the app controller level and then show the login screen.

What i have done (not the best way) is listen for this event in my app controller and redirect to login route -

```
$scope.$on('event:auth-loginRequired', function() {
    $location.path('/login');
});
```

Comment: This quite don't answer the question, but I will try to take a look at that one